# Using MOJOS in H2O Steam Prediction Service Builder

Tags: h2o

In `h2o`'s documentation for the Steam Prediction Service Builder, [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/prediction_service.html#about-the-h2o-prediction-service-builder), it says that the service builder can compile both `h2o` `pojo`s (.java files) and `mojo`s (downloaded from `h2o flow` in my case as a .zip (version 3.10.5.2), which I have been using in the manner shown [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/MOJO_QuickStart.md#step-2-compile-and-run-the-mojo)). However, doing something like this:

[image]

gives this error:

```
Problem accessing /makewar. Reason:

    Compilation of pojo failed exit value 1  warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
error: Class names, 'drf_denials_v4.zip', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
1 warning
```

So how can I use mojo files in the servicec builder? DO I need to use the "exported" model file from `h2o flow` rather than the "downloaded" zip file? The reason that I need to use `mojo`s rather than the .java `pojo`s is that my model is too large to fit in the `pojo` downloadable from `h2o flow`.

**UPDATE**:

Trying to use the CLI with the command:

```
$ curl -X POST --form mojo=@drf_denials_v4.zip --form jar=@h2o-genmodel.jar localhost:55000/makewar > drf_denials_v4.war
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  106M  100 53.6M  100 52.7M  6748k  6632k  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  229k
```

in the dir. containing the relevant files, then using the command:

```
prediction-service-builder git:(master)$ java -jar jetty-runner-9.3.9.M1.jar --port 55001 ~/Documents/h2o_production/mojos/drf_denials_v4/drf_denials_v4.war
```

gives the output:

```
2017-09-21 12:33:58.226:INFO::main: Logging initialized @232ms
2017-09-21 12:33:58.234:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2017-09-21 12:33:58.558:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.9.M1
2017-09-21 12:33:59.557:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
2017-09-21 12:34:00.068 -1000 [main] INFO ServletUtil - modelNames size 1
2017-09-21 12:34:01.285 -1000 [main] INFO ServletUtil - added model drf_denials_v4  new size 1
2017-09-21 12:34:01.290 -1000 [main] INFO ServletUtil - added 1 models
2017-09-21 12:34:01.291:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4c75cab9{/,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-55001-drf_denials_v4.war-_-any-39945022624149883.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///home/reedv/Documents/h2o_production/mojos/drf_denials_v4/drf_denials_v4.war}
2017-09-21 12:34:01.321:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@176c9571{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:55001}
2017-09-21 12:34:01.322:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @3329ms
```

Going to localhost:55001, and trying to make a prediction, I see:
[image]

Notice that a prediction is given with a label, but there are no parameter input fields present and I get the cli error message:

```
2017-09-21 12:35:11.270:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1531448569-12: Error for /info
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:270)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:101)
    at java.io.StringWriter.append(StringWriter.java:143)
    at java.io.StringWriter.append(StringWriter.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:519)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$5.write(TypeAdapters.java:210)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$5.write(TypeAdapters.java:194)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:640)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:595)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:575)
    at InfoServlet.doGet(InfoServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
```

The cli `pojo` [example](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder#using-the-cli) works, but trying to use my `mojo` zip does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the UI has not been updated for mojo functionality yet. You can however use the command line to build war files with mojos.

Run this from your command line:

`curl -X POST --form mojo=drf_denials_v4.zip --form jar=h2o-genmodel.jar localhost:55000/makewar > example.war`

Then run the war file in the normal way.

For more information see: https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder

Comment: Thanks. The cli example from the github page works for me, but this command does not. I have updated my original post to add what happened when trying to run your provided command.

Comment: Looks like you ran out of memory. Try with `-Xmx4g` or something like that. Command then is `java -Xmx4g -jar jetty-runner-9.3.9.M1.jar --port 55001 ~/Documents/h2o_production/mojos/drf_denials_v4/drf_denials_v4.war`

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I can now click predict and get a label as in the update screenshot without any error messages in the cli. But like in the updated screenshot, there are still no input fields (the model takes 20 inputs and I have successfully predicted on them when using the mojo zip in a java file as in the mojo quickstart example (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/MOJO_QuickStart.md#step-2-compile-and-run-the-mojo)). What could be causing this? Inspecting the page html, it's not as if the input fields are hidden.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked. I suspect the answer again is that the UI has not been updated to handle mojos. It should work fine to predict using the command line. Then you'd do something like `curl -X POST --data '{Var1:  Val1}' localhost:55001/predict` etc.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be that case. Unfortunately it also nullifies a big portion of the reason the service builder would have been useful in my case, since not having a UI interface means I can't take advantage of the input selection drop downs for categorical inputs. Anyways, thank you for your knowledge.