# h2o steam deployed model has no input fields in prediction service

Tags: h2o

When trying to use the `prediction service` for a model deployed by `steam`, this is what I see:

[image]

Notice that when I click the "Predict" button, I get a prediction label response from the model. But there are no input fields being displayed. Why is this happening?

I start my steam session like this:

1. I launch `h2o flow`

   `java -Xmx4g -jar h2o.jar`
2. I start the steam jetty server for the prediction service (as instructed [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/Installation.html#start-steam-locally)):

   `java -Xmx6g -jar var/master/assets/jetty-runner.jar var/master/assets/ROOT.war`

I use -Xmx6g because I was getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`
 from the prediction service earlier.

3. I launch the steam server:

   `./steam serve master --prediction-service-host=localhost --prediction-service-port-range=12345:22345`

I use a custom port range for the prediction service since I was having problems deploying models from `steam` where it could not access port 8080 (if anyone knows a better way around this please let me know). From here, I import model from the localhost `h2o flow` server in `steam` and deploy it to get the screen show at the top of this post.

I was having problems before where the prediction service *builder* server (launched with `GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx6g ./gradlew jettyRunWar` following the instruction [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/prediction_service.html#build-and-run-the-builder-service)) was not showing input fields for .war files built from mojos (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353786/8236733)), but I am using a model imported directly from `h2o flow` into `steam` in this case. If anyone knows what is going on here it would be a big help. Thanks :)

**UPDATE**
Used a smaller similar model (POJO size of ~200MB) and can now see input fields (after waiting on the prediction service screen for ~10sec.). Can't tell what kind of file the model is currently being transferred as under the hood though, I assume POJO now. One weird thing though is that the input fields also include the models binomial response labels (as if the user could just choose the response as input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in this other question [Using MOJOS in H2O Steam Prediction Service Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353578/using-mojos-in-h2o-steam-prediction-service-builder/46353786#46353786)  this is because the UI has not been updated to handle MOJOs, it currently only handles POJOs.

You can use command line (or other tools) to send data to and get predictions from the prediction service. How to do this is explained here: https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder

Comment: Does this mean that, under the hood, `steam` passes all models to the prediction service as `mojos`?

Comment: If I remember right it passes some models as MOJOs (tree-based models), but other ones are passed as POJOs.

Comment: This is open source, and you are welcome to submit changes: https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md