# h2o steam prediction service results not being recognized as a BinaryPrediction for binomial estimator

Tags: h2o

I have a DRF model created in `h2o flow` that is supposed to be binomial and `flow` indicates that it is binomial

[image]

but I am having a problem where, importing it into `h2o steam` and deploying it to the prediction service, the model does not seem to be recognized as binomial. The reason I think this is true is shown below. The reason this is a problem is because I think it is what is causing the prediction service to NOT show the confidence value for the prediction (this reasoning is also shown below).

In the prediction service, I can get a prediction label, but no values filled in the index-label-probability table.

[image]

Using the browser inspector (google chrome), the prediction output seems to depend on a file called `predict.js`.

[image]

In order to get the prediction probability values to show in the prediction service, it seems like [this](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L199) block of code needs to run to get to [this](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L204) line. Opening the `predict.js` file within the inspector on the prediction service page and adding some debug output statements at some of the top lines (indicated with DEBUG/ENDDEBUG comments in the code below), my [showResults](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L171)() function then looks like:

```
function showResult(div, status, data) {
    ////////// DEBUG
    console.log("showResult entered")
    ////////// ENDDEBUG

    var result = '<legend>Model Predictions</legend>'

    //////////  DEBUG
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.classProbabilities)
    console.log("**showResult: isBinPred=" + isBinaryPrediction)
    ////////// ENDDEBUG

    if (data.classProbabilities) {
      ////////// DEBUG
      console.log("**showResult: data.classProbabilities not null")
      ////////// ENDDEBUG

      // binomial and multinomial
      var label = data.label;
      var index = data.labelIndex;
      var probs = data.classProbabilities;
      var prob = probs[index];

      result += '<p>Predicting <span class="labelHighlight">' + label + '</span>';
      if (probs.length == 2) {
        result += ' based on max F1 threshold </p>';
      }
      result += ' </p>';
      result += '<table class="table" id="modelPredictions"> \
                  <thead> \
                    <tr> \
                      <th>Index</th> \
                      <th>Labels</th> \
                      <th>Probability</th> \
                    </tr> \
                   </thead> \
                   <tbody> \
                  ';

      if (isBinaryPrediction) {
        var labelProbabilitiesMapping = [];
        outputDomain.map(function(label, i) {
          var labelProbMap = {};
          labelProbMap.label = outputDomain[i];
          labelProbMap.probability = probs[i];
          if (i === index) {
            labelProbMap.predicted = true;
          }
          labelProbMap.originalIndex = i;
          labelProbabilitiesMapping.push(labelProbMap);
        });
        labelProbabilitiesMapping.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b.probability - a.probability;
        });
        var limit = labelProbabilitiesMapping.length > 5 ? 5 : labelProbabilitiesMapping.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
          if (labelProbabilitiesMapping[i].predicted === true) {
            result += '<tr class="rowHighlight">'
          } else {
            result += '<tr>'
          }
          result += '<td>' + labelProbabilitiesMapping[i].originalIndex + '</td><td>' + labelProbabilitiesMapping[i].label + '</td> <td>' + labelProbabilitiesMapping[i].probability.toFixed(4) + '</td></tr>';
        }
      } else {
        for (var label_i in outputDomain) {
          if (parseInt(label_i) === index ){
            result += '<tr class="rowHighlight">'
          } else {
            result += '<tr>'
          }
          result += '<td>' + label_i + '</td><td>' + outputDomain[label_i] + '</td> <td>' + probs[label_i].toFixed(4) + '</td></tr>';
        }
      }

      result += '</tbody></table>';
    }
    else if ("cluster" in data) {
      // clustering result
      result = "Cluster <b>" + data["cluster"] + "</b>";
    }
    else if ("value" in data) {
      // regression result
      result = "Value <b>" + data["value"] + "</b>";
    }
    else if ("dimensions" in data) {
      // dimensionality reduction result
      result = "Dimensions <b>" + data["dimensions"] + "</b>";
    }
    else {
      result = "Can't parse result: " + data;
    }

    div.innerHTML = result;
  }
```

and clicking the "predict" in the prediction service now generates the console output:

[image]

If I were to add a statement `isBinaryPrediction = true` to forcec the global variable to true (around [here](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L198)) and run the prediction again, the console shows:

[image]

indicating that the [variable](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L201) `outputDomain` is undefined. The variable `outputDomain` seems to be set in the [function](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L57) `showModel`. This function appears to run when the page loads, so I can't edit it in the chrome inspector to see what the variable values are. If anyone knows how to fix this problem (getting the prediction probability values to show up for `h2o steam`'s prediction service for binomial models) it would a big help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI has not been updated to handle MOJOs yet and there seems to be a bug. You're welcome to contribute: https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: I don't think that the model is being imported as a MOJO in this case, since I am not experiencing the same kinds of problems that I was having as in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46353578/8236733) when it was more likely that the model was being imported as a MOJO. The model I am using now is much smaller (200MB as opposed to 800MB).

Comment: I believe Steam always sends DRF models as MOJOs. You can try and export it as a POJO and build a prediction service from that, and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Useful note for others: From the prediction service url (eg. localhost:16563), you can navigate to "/info"  subdomain (eg. localhost:16563/info) to see a json map of some of the info about the model being used.

Comment: I have posted my own solution, but it is very hacky. You seem to know way more than me and if you could add any insights based my posted answer, it would be appreciated. By the way, if you don't mind, are you a contributor to the `h2o steam` project or affiliated with `h2o` in some other direct way?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very hacky, but works for my *particular* case (ie. I have a *DRF*, *binomial* model in h2o steam that is not being recognized as a binary model (how I know this is shown in this answer)).

**Solution:**
In my original post, there was a variable `outputDomain` that was `undefined`. Looking at the source code, that variable is set to (what is *supposed* to be) the domain labels of the output response for the model, [here](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L104). I changed this line from `outputDomain = domains[i1];` to `outputDomain = domains[i1-1];`. My output after clicking the predict button looks like:

[image]

From the official linux download for `h2o steam`, you can access the prediction service `predict.js` file by opening `steam-1.1.6-linux-amd64/var/master/assets/ROOT.war/extra/predict.js`, then saving changes and relaunching the jetty server `$ java -Xmx6g -jar var/master/assets/jetty-runner.jar var/master/assets/ROOT.war`.

**Causes?**: 
I suspect the problem has something to do with that fact that the global variable `isBinaryPrediction` in predict.js seems to remain `false` for my model. The reason that `isBinaryPrediction` is false seems to be because in the function [showInputParameters()](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L153), `data.m` has no field _problem_type. Using `console.dir(data, {depth: null})` in the inspector console to see the fields of `data.m`, I see that the expectedd field `data.m._problem_type` does not exist and so returns undefined, thus `isBinaryPrediction` is never set true ([here](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/prediction-service-builder/src/main/webapp/extra/predict.js#L157)).

[image]

Why this is happening, I do not know. I have only used DRF models in steam so far and this may be a problem with that model, but I have not tested. If anyone knows why this may be happening, please let me know.